# How can I redirect through rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

routes.rb

```
namespace :user do
  resources :people 
end
```

URL1

```
"abc.com/user/people" -> User::PeopleController#index
```

URL2

```
  "abc.com/user/people?abc=123" -> User::PeopleController#create
```

I want to redirect User::PeopleController#index to User::PeopleController#list through routes.rb.

```
 match "user/people", :to => redirect("/user/people/list")
```

When I write above code into the routes.rb. It redirect Url1 and Url2 to the list action.
I just want to redirect Url1 only.

Comment: Can you post your routes.rb file?

Comment: Why you want my whole routes.rb file ?

Comment: @krunalshah why does it need to be in `routes.rb`? You can easily check in the controller if the params are present, and if they are - redirect.

Comment: If it's very large, just post the section of it with the routes relevant to this question. I've got a clue as to what is going wrong, but I don't want to be guessing ;)

Comment: @Vucko I just wanted remove my index method from controller. So It would be better If I can directly redirect from the routes file.

Comment: @fivedigit I have added my routes in question.

Answer (score 0):

in rails4, this is how you would do it

```
match "blupp", via: :get, to: 'home#index', constraints: -> (request) { request.query_parameters.blank? }
```